# Upper bound on norm of Hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms, hermitian-matrices

I encountered this statement in [this](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1959-092-02/S0002-9947-1959-0109367-6/S0002-9947-1959-0109367-6.pdf) paper about random walks on groups by H. Kesten (page 336, (1.2)). Although he gives a reference, I cannot find the proof there. The statement looks like a simple exercise in linear algebra (and it may very well be one), but I spent quite some time on it without finding a proof:

Let $A=(a_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$ be a Hermitian matrix. 
Then we have
$$||A||\leq \sup_{1\leq i\leq n} \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}|,$$
where $||A||=\sup_{||x||=1}||Ax||$ is the operator norm with respect to the standard Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: If you understand the operator norm to be equivalent to the maximal singular value of $A$, then this is an immediate consequence of (a) Gerschgorin Discs or (b) the Schur Test

Comment: @user8675309 Thanks a lot! I would like to accept this as the correct answer, but this is not possible for comments - maybe you want to repost it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing one understands the operator 2 norm to be equivalent to the maximal singular value of $A$, this result follows from applying either (a) Gerschgorin Discs (since $A$ is Hermitian the modulus of each of its eigenvalues equals one of its singular values) or (b) the Schur Test.

**proof of the Schur Test**
for arbitrary $A \in \mathbb C^{m\times n}$
and $m$ dimensional $\mathbf x$ and $n$ dimensional $\mathbf y$, **each constrained to have unit length** (2 norm).

$R := \max_{i} \sum_{j=1}^n \vert a_{i,j}\vert$
$C := \max_{j} \sum_{i=1}^m \vert a_{i,j}\vert$
(max L1 norm amongst respective row and column vectors of $A$)

$$
\begin{align} 
&\big \vert \mathbf x^*A\mathbf y\big \vert\\ 
& \leq \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n \big \vert x_i a_{i,j} y_j\big \vert\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n \big(\vert x_i\vert \vert  a_{i,j}\vert^\frac{1}{2}\big) \big(\vert  a_{i,j}\vert^\frac{1}{2}\vert y_j\vert\big)\\
&\leq \Big(\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n \big(\vert x_i\vert \vert  a_{i,j}\vert^\frac{1}{2}\big)^2\Big)^\frac{1}{2} \Big(\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n \big(\vert  a_{i,j}\vert^\frac{1}{2}\vert y_j\vert\big)^2\Big)^\frac{1}{2}\\
&= \Big(\sum_{i=1}^m \vert x_i\vert^2 \big(\sum_{j=1}^n \vert  a_{i,j}\vert\big) \Big)^\frac{1}{2} \Big(\sum_{j=1}^n \vert y_j\vert^2 \big(\sum_{i=1}^m  \vert  a_{i,j}\vert\big)  \Big)^\frac{1}{2}\\ 
&\leq \Big(\sum_{i=1}^m \vert x_i\vert^2 \cdot R  \Big)^\frac{1}{2} \Big(\sum_{j=1}^n \vert y_j\vert^2 \cdot C  \Big)^\frac{1}{2}\\ 
&=  \Big(\sqrt{R\cdot C}\Big)  \Big(\sum_{i=1}^m \vert x_i\vert^2 \Big)^\frac{1}{2} \Big(\sum_{j=1}^n \vert y_j\vert^2   \Big)^\frac{1}{2}\\ 
&=  \sqrt{R\cdot C}  \\
\end{align}  
$$where the inequalities are (1) Triangle Inequality, (2) Cauchy-Schwarz, (3) a point-wise bound (then summing over the bound)

*remark:*
i.)  for this problem, $R=C$ because $A$ is Hermitian so we recover the bound in the problem statement.
ii.) in general if $A=U\Sigma V^*$ with maximal singular value $\sigma_1$ then selecting $\mathbf x:=\mathbf u_1$ and $\mathbf y:= \mathbf v_1$ gives
$\sigma_1 =  \mathbf u_1^*A\mathbf v_1 = \big \vert \mathbf u_1^*A\mathbf v_1\big \vert\leq \sqrt{R\cdot C}$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just for the sake of completeness, this gives an upper bound on the norm of A because $||A||=\sup_{||x||=1}||Ax||=\sup (\langle Ax,Ax \rangle)^{1/2}=sup(\langle A^2x,x\rangle)^{1/2}=\sup(x^TAx^TxAx)^{1/2}=\sup x^TAx \leq  \sup_{||x||=||y||=1}x^TAy$.

Comment: your chain of equalities is close but not quite right.  E.g.  suppose $A$ is Hermitian negative definite, then  $0 \lt \sup_{||x||=1}||Ax|| = \sup x^*Ax \lt 0$ which is a contradiction. (Since we're talking re: Hermitian matrices, the use of $^T$ for transpose is ill advised when dealing with quadratic forms-- though the OP talks Hermitian matrices and $\mathbb R^n$ which is also confusing.) Probably better to write $\sup_{||x||=1}||Ax||^2\leq \sup_{||x||=1}||A^{*}Ax||\cdot\sup_{||x||=1}||x|| = \sup_{||x||=1}||A^{*}Ax||= \sigma_1^2$ then take square roots.  (The inequality is Cauchy-Schwarz)