# How to prove $\|A\|_2 \le \sqrt{\|A\|_1^{\vphantom t}\cdot\|A\|_{\infty}}$ using Holder's Inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I was reading the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Equivalence_of_norms) article on matrix norms, and it claims that for $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$, we have
$$\|A\|_2 \le \sqrt{\|A\|_1 \cdot \|A\|_{\infty}}$$
which is a "special case of Holder's Inequality."

I know [a couple proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3953242/if-a-is-an-m-times-n-matrix-show-that-a-2-le-sqrta-1a-infty) of this matrix inequality, but I would like to solve it using Holder.

For vectors, Holder gives
$$|x^*y| \le \|x\|_p\|x_q\| \hspace{1cm} p, q \ge 1 \text{ with } \frac 1p + \frac 1q = 1$$
and taking the limit as $p \to 1^+$ we have
$$|x^*y| \le \|x\|_1 \|y\|_{\infty}.$$

But I haven't been able to apply a similar reasoning to the matrix norms.

Comment: Despite its appearance, this is actually Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3937731 .