# Is there any mathematical method or algorithm to estimate the maximum and minimum eigenvalues of $AA^{T}$ given $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that A is a known $M*N$ real matrix. ($N>M$)

I would like to estimate the maximum and minimum eigenvalues of $AA^{T}$ in low time complexity.

SVD can solve this problem easily but the time complexity is high ($O(M^2N)$). Computing $AA^{T}$ and $A^{-1}$ are also not acceptable.

I think finding the lower bound of minimum eigenvalues and the upper bound of maximum eigenvalues is also good enough.

Thanks.

Comment: for the maximum, you just need the norm of $A$

Comment: Out of curiosity, where do your constraints on the time complexity come from?

Comment: And for the minimum, you need the norm of $A^{-1}$.

Comment: @littleO Since the time complexity of SVD is $O(M^2N)$ (if N > M). In my research, this high complexity is too high.

Comment: I'd suggest the Schur Test to upper bound $\sigma_{max}$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3935647/upper-bound-on-norm-of-hermitian-matrix/

Comment: @Miku_39 Have you heard about [Lanczos algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm) or [Arnoldi iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnoldi_iteration)? These are the efficient methods for sparse matrices.

Comment: @andywiecko I will read the wiki. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a random vector $v \in \mathbb R^M$.
For any positive integer $k$ the maximum eigenvalue of $A A^T$
$\ge \|(A A^T)^k v\|/\|(A A^T)^{k-1} v\|$; with probability $1$
the limit of this as $k \to \infty$ is the actual largest eigenvalue.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, can you tell me what is the name of this theorem. I want to learn it.