# Inequality between norm 1,norm 2 and norm $\infty$ of Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces, holder-inequality

Suppose $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix.

Then Prove that,
\begin{equation*}
\|A\|_2\leq \sqrt{\|A\|_1 \|A\|_{\infty}}
\end{equation*}

I have proved the following relations:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\|A\|_{\infty}\leq \|A\|_2\leq\sqrt{m}\|A\|_{\infty}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\|A\|_{1}\leq \|A\|_2\leq\sqrt{n}\|A\|_{1}
\end{align*}
Also I feel that somehow Holder's inequality for the special case when $p=1$ and $q=\infty$ might be useful.But I couldn't prove that.

Edit: I would like to have a prove that do not use the information that $\|A\|_2=\sqrt{\rho(A^TA)}$

Usage of inequalities like Cauchy Schwartz or Holder is fine.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. The first comment refers to an answer that uses the result that spectral radius of $A^TA$ is equivalent to the norm 2. But I do not want to use that result. The second comment however seems helpful where the answer uses schur test. The answer however assums A is hermitian. Can you elaborate, how to apply that method for arbitrary matrix A?

Comment: I have linked to those threads because they look like the identical question to me. If there are certain results that you can not use then I would suggest that you update the question accordingly.

Comment: I have edited the answer accordingly... btw thanks for Approach 0....I didn't know about it.

Comment: I have retracted my closing vote. As far as I can see, the other answers use the characterization of $\Vert A \Vert_2$ via the spectral radius, not the definition as an induced norm.

Comment: If you understand the operator 2 norm to be given by the largest singular value, then this proof falls out of the Schur Test.  I gave a proof here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3935647/upper-bound-on-norm-of-hermitian-matrix/

Comment: A more general version has been asked and answered recently: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4236021/42969.

Answer (score 1):

$$\|A\|_{2}^2=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{m}|a|^2_{ij}
=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{m}|a_{ij}||a_{ij}|\leq
\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{m}|a_{ij}|\max_{\substack{1\leq i\leq n\\1\leq j\leq n}}{|a_{ij}|}
$$
$$=\max_{\substack{1\leq i\leq n\\1\leq j\leq n}}{|a_{ij}|}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{m}|a_{ij}|
=\|A\|_{\infty}\|A\|_{1}.$$

Remark: The same proof works almost identically if the $1-$ norm
and $2-$norm are defined by
$\|A\|_{1}=
\sum_{j=1}^{n}\max_{1\leq i \leq m}{|a_{ij}|}$
and
$\|A\|^2_{2}=
\sum_{j=1}^{n}\max_{1\leq i \leq m}{|a_{ij}|^2}$
or $\|A\|_{1}=
\sum_{i=1}^{m}\max_{1\leq j \leq n}{|a_{ij}|}$
and
$\|A\|^2_{2}=
\sum_{i=1}^{m}\max_{1\leq j \leq n}{|a_{ij}|^2}$.

Comment: As I learned it  $\Vert A \Vert_2$is the matrix norms induces by the corresponding vector norm, and $\Vert A \Vert_F = \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{m}|a|^2_{ij}}$ is the Frobenius norm. You seem to use different definitions.

Comment: Yes, by $\|A\|_2$, I meant the norm induced the vector norm. However I have proved that Frobenius norm is larger than it. But still I could not understand the answer given by Medo. For $\|A\|_1$, I have to take the highest column sum, not the highest element among all the elements in the matrix $A$. Kindly explain that part

Comment: @Newrion  How about you define the norms you are considering in question so that we can help you

Comment: @Martin R  $\|\cdot \|_{2}\leq \|\cdot \|_{F}$.